# Accidentally cleared TPM on BitLocked computer

Tags: windows, boot, bios, bitlocker, tpm

One of my technicians was supposed to image a computer that has BitLocker enabled. He didn't know the access pin and instead inserted a Dell boot disk to do a soft-restore (keeping all of the clients files and resting windows). There was a warning notifying him that he was clearing the TPM. He pushed "OK" and now the computer boots to a black screen. I have the recovery key and can access the BIOS but that is about it.

I have been googling for a few hours now and I cant find anything that will help. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be able to add the disk to another machine, use the recovery key to unlock the disk, then remove bitlocker. I want to emphasize the "in theory" part as I've never done it, and t is simply theory (IMHO) until it works in the real world.

Comment: That was going to be my next step. Thanks for the reassurance. I will have to try this in the morning.

Comment: In theory. Based on the description, I rather suspect that the contents of the drive are permanently lost.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to get anyones hope up too much, but it's certainly worth the shot.